# Rails providing search through API with themoviedb-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

I am creating movie/series focused web application. In this application users would be able to search through movies/series and subscribe them. I want to provide users with the movie/series search engine through API. In my app's database I have no information about movies/series, so when the users is typing title in the search field I need to send a search request to API to fetch movies/series that match the given pattern. The problem is that at this point I don't see any way of implementing this functionality. I thought about another controller e.i. Searcher. That's fine, but I would like to put this search field in my app's layout so it would be available everywhere not only for users that are on particular URL.

Answer (score 1):

First have you an API key from IMDB API ? (https://github.com/18Months/themoviedb-api)

Make it a remote form and catch results through Ajax callback `ajax:complete`.
When a request is made, show a loader on the view to wait the time you call the api.

Call Your SearchController throught its route.

In your controller Search in you DB, if you do not find it, make an API call, save in DB and serve the result.

(Would be better to call the API in background, and serve results through Websockets but would be over-engineering right now.)

Comment: So I need to make a form and when it is submitted, search data goes to my Search controller, then Search is responsible for gathering data whether it is from my db or through movieAPI. In order to make search form part of my main layout, I need to save all results of my search action to my db, am I right?

Comment: It is more to avoid reaching API's quotas limits.And making the form part of your layout does not require anything but you to paste it inside the layout. it works everywhere...

Comment: Yeah I got it. I don't need to save my search results and I can't reach quotas limits. I think that the reasonable way would be to implement a quotas limit mechanism on my page (not on API's side). Back to your answer, what did you mean by calling the API in background? As a part of browser extension?

Comment: No, I mean by using something like sidekiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq so you can do everything through nice Ajax and even Websockets. But that's really AFTER it already works. Try to implement the search in a non-optimized way first. Optimise once its works. (and check the answer if it's ok for you)